# Angular 2 - calling a component

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am developing an ANgular 2 application.

I have a small form in which is in home.component.ts, which looks like below.[image]

Once the user click on Submit button. Datatable should be loaded with the matching results. like below. This is a different component result.component.ts

[image]

What is the best approach to call the result.component from the home.component?
First component should pass the resulting data set to the second one.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: I will go through this. Thanks @echonax

Comment: Is the datatable in the same component as `home.component`? How does the Datatable load the new results? Are all data being loaded and then filtered? or is it gonna invoke a `http` call to the server and fetch new results?

Comment: Yes. getting the data from the same database. Once the user clicks on submit button there will be a server call using web API to load data as per the selection criteria given.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the result by its selector which is defined in the @Component Directive and pass the result via an @Input:

**result.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search-result',
  teplateUrl: './result.component.html'
})
export class ResultComponent {
  @Input() result: Result;
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
  searchString: string;
  result: Result;

  performSearch(searchString: string) {
    // perform API call here and save result to this.result
  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<label for="q"><strong>Territory:</strong></label><br>
<input type="text" name="q" ([ngModel])="searchString"><br>
<button (click)="performSearch(searchString)">Search</button>
Result:
<search-result result="result"></search-result>
```

**result.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of result">
    <td>{{ item }}
  </tr>
</table>
```